# how to debug request.post in nodejs

Tags: node.js, debugging, post, request

could some give me idea to debug the below snippet.

```
var request = require('request');

function sendINFO() {
    var jsonString = {
        reportType: 'customer',
        comment: customerDetails.cust_id,
        imageUrl: customerDetails.url1
    }
    console.log('json string', jsonString)
    request.post(
        'http://52.7.0.131/SendInfo/XC1K1AZ9', {
            json: jsonString
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
            console.log('response after adding report', response, 'error', error)
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
            }
        }
    );
}
```

i want to check whether it's working or not. and how to test this with postman api

many thanks for any help

Comment: in postman hit http://52.7.0.131/SendInfo/XC1K1AZ9 this url with method as POST and send jsonString data in raw body and format as JSON

Comment: i cant understand what you're saying . 

i just did like this 52.7.0.131/AddReport/FC5E1BF6', {json: jsonString}  

then i chose raw, there i gave like below
var jsonString = {
        reportType: 'customer',
        comment: customerDetails.cust_id,
        imageUrl: customerDetails.url1
    }

Comment: go through my answer, Below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in postman in URL section add 52.7.0.131/SendInfo/XC1K1AZ9 this url with method as POST then Navigate to body tag and then select raw radio button. Then in same row you will see [Text] combo box click on that and select JSON(application/json). Then paste only `{ reportType: 'customer', comment: customerDetails.cust_id, imageUrl: customerDetails.url1 }`  this part of json below and click on Send button.

Comment: thanks man , now got it clearly. how would i test without using postman

Comment: can you tell me how to debug that entire function . i just check that api alone. its working fine. but as its coming under that function its not working .. how to debug this "function sendINFO(){}

Comment: in that case go for webstorm editor . it has provided great features fo debugging. It is paid. having 30 days trail version.you can try that.
other than this node insepctor is there .But webstorm is best